# Write background command output (stdout) to file during execution

Tags: python, linux, bash, stdout

I have a command that takes a long time that I like to run in the background like this:

```
python3 script.py -f input.key -o output >> logs/script.log 2>&1 &
```

This works perfectly in the sense that the command is indeed in the background and I can check the output and potential errors later.

The main problem is the output is only appended after the command is completely finished, whereas I would like to have up-to-date log messages so I check the progress.

So currently the log would be empty and than suddenly at 08:30 two lines would appear:

```
[08:00] Script starting...
[08:30] Script finished!
```

Instead, I would like to have output saved to file before the command is completely finished.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24621790/realtime-output-redirection)  and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe) post. I guess in mac pipe doesn’t do buffering because I  am getting realtime output. So can’t test it.

Comment: Can you show us how you print from python? If I remember some calls are buffered and you might have to call `sys.stdout.flush()`

Comment: I use regular `print()` statements. Buffering was indeed the problem, and your solution might work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are calling a `Python` script you would want to use the `-u` option, which forces the `stdout` and `stderr` streams to be unbuffered.

```
$ python3 -u script.py -f input.key -o output >> logs/script.log 2>&1 &
```

You can check the log periodically using `cat` or realtime in combination with `watch`:

```
$ watch cat logs/script.log
```

↳ https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u

Comment: Simple effective answer, thank you. Works both on Python 3.5 and 3.7 on my systems.